Differentialbility of a piecewise function
Consider the function $f(x) = \begin{cases} x^4 & x \in B \\ 2x^2 & x \not\in B\end{cases}$ where $B = \{\frac{\ln(p)}{p}, p > 0, p\in\mathbb{N}\}$.
Is the function differentiable at $x = 0$ and at $x = 1$?
Attempts
$x = 0$ is a point that belongs to $B$ since for $p = 1$ we get zero. But $x = 1$ doesn't belong to $B$.
So for $x = 0$ I can show the function is continuous, whereas for $x = 1$ I cannot. This is what I did in the two cases:
$$f(x = 0) = x^4 = 0\ \text{hence we need}\ \lim_{x\to 0}f(x) = f(0) \implies \lim_{x\to 0}2x^2 = x^4\big|_{x = 0} = 0$$
hence continuous
$$f(x = 1) = 2x = 2\ \text{hence we need}\ \lim_{x\to 1} f(x) = f(1) \implies \lim_{x\to 1} x^4 = 2x^2\bigg|_{x =1} \implies 1 = 2$$
Hence it's not continuous at $x = 1$.
Yet I was trying also to use the continuity with upper bounding, in this way:
$$|f(x) - f(0)| = |x^4 - 0| = x^4 \to 0\ \text{as}\ x\to 0$$
$$|f(x) - f(1)| = |2x^2 - 2| = 2(x^2-1) \to 0 \ \text{as}\ x\to 1$$
Here I see that in both cases there is continuity. Where am I wrong here? Our professor taught us to use this kind of way (the last one)...
Differentiability
I want to prove it via the definition. Hence in the first case:
$$f'(0) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{2h^2 - 0}{h} = 0$$
hence it's differentiable. Here I assumed that $0+h \not\in A$ hence $f(h) = 2h^2$.
On the other side:
$$f'(1) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h} = ...$$
here I got stuck because I don't know what $f(1+h)$ is. Considering the structure of $B$, I cannot understand this point.
Any help?
Thank you!

The case $x=1$ is the trivial one, since $f(x) = 2x^2$ in a neighbourhood of $x=1$. Hence, in that neighbourhood, the function is continuous and differentiable, including at $x=1$.

When you are checking the limit as $x$ approaches $1$, why are you using $x^4$, which is defined only for points in $B$?

On the opposite, when calculating $f'(0)$, you must consider both cases when $h\to0$. Not only $2h^2$.

Do not immediately delete a question after getting an answer.  This is disrespectful to the person who took the time to answer your question, and to future readers who might find that answer helpful.

Since for some $\epsilon >0$ we have that $B_{\epsilon}(1) \cap B = \emptyset$, the function is given by $f(x)=x^2$ in $B_{\epsilon}(1)$. Hence, it is continuous and differentiable in that whole ball, including at $x=1$.
Regarding $x=0$, since clearly $f(0) = 0$ and, for small enough $x$, we have that $|f(x) | \leq x^2$, we can conclude that $f$ is continuous at that point. As for differentiability, since
$$
\left|\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} \right| = \frac{|f(x)|}{|x|}\leq \frac{|x^2|}{|x|} = |x|,
$$
we can conclude that $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$ and $f'(0)=0$.
